# Python exiting when using tf.gfile.GFile

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I am trying to use my trained model, I used `tf.gfile.GFile` to read my labels with the following part of code:

```
import sys
import os
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import copy
import cv2
# Disable tensorflow compilation warnings
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']='2'
import tensorflow as tf
def predict(image_data):

    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, \
             {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})

    # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
    top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

    max_score = 0.0
    res = ''
    for node_id in top_k:
        human_string = label_lines[node_id]
        score = predictions[0][node_id]
        if score > max_score:
            max_score = score
            res = human_string
    return res, max_score
# Loads label file, strips off carriage return
label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line
                   in tf.gfile.GFile("logs/output_labels.txt")]
```

The issue is with this line:

`label_lines = [line.rstrip() for line in tf.gfile.GFile("logs/output_labels.txt")]`

Python process exited

[image]

and I am only getting the following warning:

`WARNING:tensorflow:From classify_webcam.py:35: The name tf.gfile.GFile is deprecated. Please use tf.io.gfile.GFile instead.`

What caused this issue?

**Note** I am using `tensorflow 1.14.0`

Comment: try to use tf.io.gfile.GFile then check a gain

Comment: The same thing, only this time exits without any warning!

Comment: add input("Press Enter to continue...") if you are using python3 and add raw_input("Press Enter to continue...") if you are using python2 , at after of that line. then scroll up to where the exception thrown , check what's wrong again, now you can see the error

Comment: It doesn't sow anything! there is no error at all.

Comment: try this : tf.io.gfile.GFile(path).read() it returns you content of the file as string , does it help? i dont know what you need :?. before that , are you sure the given path is correct ?logs/output_labels.txt

Comment: try this way : tf.io.gfile.GFile(r"igm.jpg", 'r') ; add that r param for saying read

Comment: if nothing helped at last take a look at here : https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/104102/tensorflow.gfile.GFile

Comment: Thanks, you saved my time I had an error at the file name!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208921/discussion-between-abdelaziz-mirad-and-bit).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking my `logs` folder i found that the `output_labels.txt` wasn't generated so after retraining my model and generating the labels file, `tf.io.gfile.GFile` worked fine!